# Handling HTML templates for dynamic updates to page over AJAX

Tags: php, function

Quick question for anyone who might have some input.

Normally when I have php/html blocks of code that get used on multiple pages (nav bars, footers, links, etc.) or when I use AJAX to return parts of a page, I assemble that bit of code in a separate file, then include it on the main page as well as in the php insert page to send back with AJAX return data. This works fine.

I've been experimenting with using the same concept except just wrapping my html (which includes php variables) inside of a php function in a separate file, then calling that function where I want it.

If there is a best practice for this, I'm all ears.

Comment: A “template engine” that separates concerns.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle this, but I think you'll generally find it easier to make a sort of API layer that just returns the data (often serialized to JSON) over AJAX rather than parts of the page.

This separates concerns, allowing you to maintain your API services independently from your pages.  It also allows caching of your pages.

To actually handle the updates client-side, there are a number of frameworks to choose from.  I've been using Vue.js lately myself.  There are also JavaScript-based template engines you can use to render the parts and insert the data into the page.